# convert for each to stream with if else

Tags: java, java-stream

i have a code scenario where i'm converting a for each to stream , but I'm not sure if this is the correct approach i follow

This is the for each loop:

```
List<ClassA> list=getList(); //Contains object of type ClassA
int a=0; int b=0; int c=0;
for(ClassA a: list) {
    String response=checkRespone(a.getId());
    if(reponse.equals("x"))  ++a;
    else if(reponse.equals("y")) ++b;
    else ++c;
}
```

To convert it into stream i wrote this. IS there a better way to write this ?

```
AtomicInteger a = new AtomicInteger(0);
AtomicInteger b = new AtomicInteger(0);
AtomicInteger c = new AtomicInteger(0);

list.stream().forEach(ClassA->{if(checkRespone(a.getId()).equals("x")) {a.set(a.get()+1);} else if (checkRespone(a.getId()).equals("y")) {
    b.set(b.get()+1);
} else {
    c.set(c.get()+1);
}});
```

Comment: I wouldn't use a stream for this, I would keep your current code.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen why should i not use stream for this ?

Comment: I think you should use filter on stream on each of the three conditions and then map to increment each element of the filtered lists.

Comment: Streams are nice when you use them functionally to process and produce results in a stateless way without side effects. It's pointless to just switch `for` to `forEach()`. The syntax is uglier and it's still stateful and unparallelizable. No point.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you really want to perform this functionally, you can try out `grouping` collectors. You can further avoid iterating the values to find their `sum` if you tend to use the size of the initial list to find the remaining count for variable `c`.

```
Map<String, Long> countingResponse = list.stream()
        .map(clz -> checkRespone(clz.getId()))
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()));
int a = countingResponse.getOrDefault("x", 0L).intValue();
int b = countingResponse.getOrDefault("y", 0L).intValue();
int c = list.size() - (a + b);
```

Comment: If I need to run different methods for each `X` and `Y` provided I have `X` and `Y` in my map then what should be the approach?? Clearly `getOrDefault` and `computeIfAbsent` won't work.

Comment: More precisely `if(reponse.equals("x"))  SomeMethodA();
    else if(reponse.equals("y")) SomeMethodB();
    else SomeMethodC();`

Comment: @VishwaRatna If the doubt is to treat the lookup as case-insensitive, then the `grouping` method can perform a lowercase instead of `identity` for keys. There is not much of a hint towards that in the question though.